# Crossing from Canada into the US with a rental car as a Swiss citizen: what do I need?

Tags: usa, canada, swiss-citizens

I am a Swiss (= not EU) citizen and I'm going to fly to Montreal, rent a RV and then cross into the US (Vermont). Since I won't be included in the ESTA program, what do I need in order to pass the US border? Are they going to give me a visa at the border?

Comment: Switzerland is part of the Visa Waiver Program, which enables citizens of Switzerland to travel to the United States without a visa. Source: http://www.esta.us/switzerland.html

Comment: @Kris That is an answer, why not make it so?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The US Embassy in Switzerland told me that, since we are not going to travel directly to the US (we'll fly to Montreal and than drive to Vermont), we don't need to apply for ESTA. I'm just a little bit worried about the procedure at the Canada/US border...

Comment: @Laura There is a distinction between ESTA (the authorization process when you enter the US by air) and VWP (the program that allow some people to visit without a visa, no matter how they enter). I haven't done it myself but [this earlier answer covers the procedure when coming from Canada](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13715/re-enter-usa-from-canada-with-visa-waiver-program/13750#13750)

Answer (score 3):

Officially if entering the US via land border then you do not need an ESTA, however you are still able to use the Visa Waiver Program as you come from a country that is allowed under the Visa Waiver Program.

At the border you will be required to fill in a I94W form, be photographed/finger-printed, and pay a US$6 fee.

There have recently been reports that people who have an ETSA have been able to bypass the process above. Given that an ESTA is only US$14 it may be worth applying for one anyway - at worst you end up $14 out of pocket. As best, you save yourself some trouble at the border.

Also make sure that your rental company is aware that you are driving into the US, and that you have suitable insurance coverage for the vehicle.  Not all companies allow you to cross the border, although most do.